# React Native Navigation v5 triggering a drawer from bottom tabs

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

Currently I am trying to tigger the drawer from the bottom nav as you can see here:

[image]

My current tabs is the following:

```
 <NavigationContainer>
  <Tab.Navigator
    screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
        let iconName;

        switch (route.name) {
          case 'Home':
            iconName = 'window-maximize';
            break;
          case 'Purchases':
            iconName = 'tags';
            break;
          case 'Notifications':
            iconName = 'bell';
            break;
          case 'Checkout':
            iconName = 'shopping-cart';
            break;
          case 'Orders':
            iconName = 'dollar';
            break;
          case 'Menu':
            iconName = 'navicon';
            break;
        }

        return (
          <Icon
            name={iconName}
            size={20}
            color={focused ? 'blue' : 'grey'}
          />
        );
      },
    })}
    tabBarOptions={{
      showLabel: false,
    }}>
    <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={LandingScreens} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Purchases" component={PurchasesScreens} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Checkout" component={CheckoutScreens} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Orders" component={OrdersScreens} />
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Menu"
      component={Drawer}
      listeners={({ navigation }) => ({
        tabPress: (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
        },
      })}
    />
  </Tab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

And my Drawer Component is just going to be a custom Drawer component:

```
const Drawer = ({ navigation }) => {
    const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

    return (
      <Drawer.Navigator
        drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={LandingScreens} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
  };
```

My question is something like this possible? I was trying to tigger the navigation.openDrawer() from the `tabPress` but couldn't find the method. I am doing this right, or would I need some sort of custom bottomNav? Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `DrawerActions.openDrawer`:

```js
import { DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native'

    <Tab.Screen
      name="Menu"
      component={Drawer}
      listeners={({ navigation }) => ({
        tabPress: (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();

          navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())
        },
      })}
    />
```

A better solution is to nest the tabs inside the drawer so `navigation.openDrawer()` works.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigator-specific-methods-are-available-in-the-navigators-nested-inside

Comment: I tried that above method but get an error:
The action `OPEN_DRAWER` was not handled by any navigator. Is your screen inside a Drawer navigator.

Comment: That doesn't make sense nest the tabs in the drawer?

Comment: I am reading this now, kinda makes sense for the nesting, I will give that a go, see if it helps.

Comment: Hello. I have exactly the same issue. How did You solve it ?